# Connecting to Server on One Computer from another with TCP Listener/Sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, server

I have a simple server I can run on one computer that a simple chat client can connect to. When I run the server on my local, I can connect to it fine from a client also on the local. The problem is that I can't seem to connect to the server from a client on another computer.

Some example code from the **client**:

```
static string ipAddr = "<server local IP address>";
static Int32 port = 4296;
static System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient tcpClient = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddr), port);
```

The remote client hits an exception on that last line. The specific error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred in System.dll

Additional information: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

The **server** is creating a connection in a similar fashion, on the same port, but on the localhost IP `127.0.0.1`, for reference.

I have tried forwarding the port on my router (TCP), as well as opening the inbound and outgoing ports for TCP in my Firewall (I know this isn't sustainable -- just trying to get it working at the moment).

I am pretty confident the issue is that the remote client cannot see the server, but doing a netstat on the port indicates it is listening when the server is running, and is running when the local client is connected. Checking the port through Canyouseeme does actually say that the port is not open, so have I just somehow forwarded the port incorrectly?

Any advice? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The server is creating a connection in a similar fashion, on the same port, but on the localhost IP 127.0.0.1, for reference.

The server is bound to the loop-back address. Hence when you connect from client running from same machine as server, connect is successful. If the client is external to server's machine, it cannot connect to server on 127.0.0.1 in the other machine.

Bind the server to a valid IP address, reachable from client.

Comment: Figured this out earlier but didn't get a chance to update the post. This was exactly the problem. Thanks very much for the answer, friend.